# warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] char*

Tags: c

I need to program a shell and my teacher asks us to do a username which I made by

```
char* userName = getlogin();
```

It gives me the warning in the title when I try to compile the file and segfaults when I try to run the program (and when I run it with eclipse it prints NULL)

So, my question is what so wrong with `char*`? Why does `getlogin` give me `NULL`?

Here is my code is:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[INPUT_SIZE+1]; //user's input
    char hostName[INPUT_SIZE];
    //char* userName = getlogin();
    char* userName = getpwuid(getuid());

    if (gethostname(hostName,255)< 0) {
        printf("there is no hostname\n", hostName);
        exit (200);
    }
    int code;
    code=0;
while(1)
{
    printf("%d %s@%s$ ",code,userName,hostName);


    fgets(input, INPUT_SIZE, stdin);
    if(strcmp("\n",input) == 0)
        continue;

    printf("it didn't continue\n");

    if(strcmp("exit\n",input)==0)
    {
        printf("you exit\n");
        continue;
        //exit(127);
    }
    printf("it didnt go to exit\n");
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Need to see `getpwuid()` definition. You cannot return a char* from getpwuid unless it's heap-alocated (which you're not freeing in that case) or it's global (which is unusual). Most probably, you're calling it wrong.

Comment: Also, make sure you get all prototypes you need included. Using functions without proper prototype is much too error-prone.

Comment: uncomment the `char* userName = getlogin();` and comment out the next line, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`getpwuid` returns a pointer to a `struct passwd`, not a `char*`. `getlogin` does return a `char*`. However, if you are getting errors about trying to initialize a `char*` using an `int` it is likely because `getlogin` isn't declared and the compiler is assuming it is of type `int`. Have you included the header that defines these functions? `getlogin` should be included with

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't even call `getlogin()`, you commented out that line! Uncomment the `char* userName = getlogin();` and comment out the next line, it will work.